# Design of the feed forward neural network with multiclass output and low number of inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a set of data items X<sub>ij</sub> each having 20 columns  (categorical data) and there are 30 different types of X<sub>ij</sub>

As an input to NN, I want to provide a combination of these items (8 items = 20*8 = 160 is the size of X vector)(Xi). As a result, I want a multi-class output (Y<sub>i</sub>). (Y<sub>i</sub>) is a vector of length 670 (this number may change).

X1 will be labeled as 000000000000000000100000000000000000000000010000000000001 (a total of 670 elements in a vector).
X2 will be labeled as another combination of 0's and 1's with the same length (these points out an index for another dataset with length 670)

In order to train the model, I will provide sample sets of X<sub>ij</sub> values. I decided 12 X items (12 different combinations of 30 unique items= an input of 12*160). I know this is a low number, but manually labeling is not easy, so I want to keep the number small. If you suggest to use a higher number or some other techniques I would love to listen?

In summary:
Xi (one input sample) has 160 columns consisting of 8 X<sub>ij</sub>. This may not be relevant to the network design, but I am giving this as an additional information).
Yi (corresponding label for Xi) is a vector of size 670 (may be lower or higher) consisting of 0's and 1's.
My training data would have a size 12 (questionable), that is, I will provide a 12 arrays each having a size 160.

What layers should I put in the NN? I want help in the design of the NN? I have access to pytorch library. I feel that a convolution layer would also be useful, cause not only the selection of Xiis but also the order of Xiis (The places) would change in each Xi.

Comment: to be honest, it is not clear at all what the dimensions are and what you are trying to do. What Xii is, what you want to input and etc. If you could edit and make it more clear I might help

Comment: Regular Dense layer also catches position-important traits, so Dense layer is enough for simplest network, no need for convolution. So you just do several dense layers and then softmax at the end. Also you have very few training data hence dense layers will train fast. Convolutions instead of dense layers is needed for speedup only for huge data.

Comment: Hi Arty, thanks for the response. Can you provided a more clear picture of your suggested model (including the layers and nodes for each layer) please?

Comment: @BerkayBerabi can you please help me on the formation of the NN? I am not very experienced in programming a NN.